# Issues with Security Token on AWS using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

The Full Error that I get is

```
 Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: operation error STS: 
GetCallerIdentity, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: 90e31298-9576-44d5-867b-1a6f047a787e, api error InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.

   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
   on main.tf line 5, in provider "aws":
```

Line 5 contains:

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "XXX"
  secret_key = "XXX"
  region     = "us-east-1"
}
```

I am brand new to Terraform and trying to figure things out for the first time. I checked that the Access Key and Secret Key are correct and contain no typos and that it is active on my AWS account. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which AWS provider version are you using? I think that versions 4 and higher do not let you use "unsafe" way of specifying AWS credentials. Hardcoding the AWS API keys falls in that category.

Comment: So I ran terraform --version and I got 

+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.2.0

So it does seem that I am running a version higher than 4....Im still pretty new to Terraform, do you mind explaining what the alternative to hard coding would be? Or Even providing a link to a resource that does?

Comment: Take a look here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/version-4-upgrade#changes-to-authentication

Comment: @MarkoE I think is still possible to use hard-coded variable in provider block for the authentication
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#static-credentials

Of course is unsafe and not suggested method.

Steel1012 Try with another authentication method, like setting the environment variables for duble check

Comment: @DaniloCacace True, I agree, it was a rash comment. :)